# Getting a bunch of GORM objects where two attributes of each object have a certain value

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a GORM object with a bunch of properties

```
MyGormObject {
    String prop1;
    String prop2;
    String prop3;
    ...
}
```

I have a list of maps - where each map has a a specific value for prop1 and prop2. 
I want to find all MyGormObjects that have a prop1 and prop2 that match a prop1, prop2 map pair.

If it was just a single pair,I was trying to match I could do:

```
static MyGormObject get(String prop1, long prop2) {
    find 'from MyGormObject where prop1=:prop1 and prop2=:prop2',
            [prop1: prop1, prop2: prop2]
}
```

Any ideas how I could match for a list of pairs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should build a dynamic criteria. Something like this:

```
def m =[
  [key1: 'value1a', key2: 'value2a'], 
  [key1: 'value1b', key2: 'value2b']
]

def results = MyDomain.withCriteria { m ->
  or {
    m.each { v ->
      and {
        eq('key1', v.key1)
        eq('key2', v.key2)
      } // match the pair of values
    }
  } // match any of the pairs
}
```

The above will match any domain class with either of the pairs in the list. In order to match any of the pairs in the list it has to be an or, and also the properties must be wrapped in an and {} as well so they are matched as a pair and not independent of one another.

Comment: I didn't read the question properly, I think you're right, apologies

Comment: No worries. I was just concerned that I totally missed something. Thanks for the assist. (:

Comment: I don’t think that is going to work.  It looks like you expect a Map (m) to be passed as an argument to the withCriteria closure.

Comment: I am referring to the "MyDomain.withCriteria { m ->” in the suggested solution.

Comment: It's a list of maps actually.

Comment: I believe that it goes down to the question: Can we write it in the SQL? If so, then there is fair chance that it can be handled by GORM/Hibernate. But I doubt it.
I'd suggest using the OR approach, or using the IN statement for the prop1 and then in second step matching for prop2 values in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?…

```
def listOfMaps = ...

def results = MyDomain.withCriteria { 
    or {
        listOfMaps.each { map ->
            // if you need to impose a check here
            // to make sure the keys exist, do that.
            // this code assumes they exist...
            def key1 = map.key1
            def key2 = map.key2
            and {
                eq 'key1', key1
                eq 'key2', key2
            }
        }
    }
}
```